# PHP mail: failed to connect to mailserver

Tags: php, email

```
ini_set("SMTP","xx.xx.xx.xx");
ini_set("smtp_port","25");
ini_set("sendmail_from","info@yoursite.com");
$to = "xxa@txxs.com";
$subject = "Test";
$subject = ltrim($subject);
$message = "Test";
$message = ltrim($message);
$headers = "Test";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers, 'O DeliveryMode=b');
```

this code works for one of my server but not the other
I get "Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver"
can you help provide me with possible cause? 
I can ping the mail host on both boxes
this drives me nut!

Comment: Are you on Windows? the smtp/smtp_port options only apply for Windows hosts. On Unix/Linux, PHP will invoke sendmail or equivalent directly.

Comment: And are you running an SMTP server on your machine (e.g IIS's?) It has to be running and actively listening on port 25, plus allowing connections from localhost, plus allowing anonymous connections from localhost.

Comment: no.the smtp server is on different box. I can ping the smtp server fine. again, I put the code on different server and it works fine.

Comment: "failed to connect" could be just that. if you've got a telnet client on the server, try to telnet from the server to the smtp server's port 25. if that fails to connect, then it's a networking issue. If it does connect, then something's goofy with php and/or iis.

Comment: I found the issue. It's the da** McAfee, blocking the port (not the firewall). Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have postfix, sendmail, whatever you are using installed? PHP doesn't send mail on it's own, that is just a "wrapper" function to make it easy to format the email message.

Also check to see if your server has a firewall like IPTables blocking access to port 25.

Comment: Firewall is off. Internal Sendmail Support for Windows is enabled (according to phpinfo)

Answer (score 0):

turns out I have this mcafee who is blocking the port